# Recover partition from hard drive showing wrong capacity

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a 1TB hard drive that started making problems a few weeks ago. It was sometimes corrupting some of the data on the drive forcing me to run fsck before booting into the system. This worked for a while so that I was able to save the most important data but there is still some data left for which I did not have enough space until now.

Unfortunately, the drive seems to be completed fried now. The system does not show the correct capacity of the drive but assumes the largest possible 16EB. In addition, no partitions can be found anymore although there should be six of them (whole Linux System, ext4 partitions). That makes it impossible to recover it with most tools including testdisk. It is also not possible to search for any backup superblocks with mkfs for example to recover the partition.

Is there any hope? If so, how might I be able to tell the disk/a recovery tool its correct capacity? Do you think the problem could be the controller board and not the disks themselves?

Output of `lsblk`, the drive is sda:

[image: Output of lsblk, the drive is sda]

Comment: The disk is done. The time to back up the data was when it started to give problems. Sorry now its a paper weight.